# How do I open a new tab when searching in Aptana Studio 3?

Tags: search, aptana, aptana3

Kind of a newbie question.

Sometimes I use the project-wide search feature, and my search results appear listed in the window below, along with the related hierarchy placement.

Let's say I double click a file.  It opens.  Fine.

However, if I double-click again on another file in the search results window, it will replace the file I just opened.  It's impossible for me to open multiple search results, short of manually opening them from the project view.

It wasn't always this way - it worked when I first installed the program, but something changed about three days in and I can't do it anymore.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Go to **Preferences** > **General** > **Search** and uncheck **Reuse editors to show matches**.